# How I can work with cross models in waterline

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline, mean.io

I am working on a project. I am using waterline ORM and my file structure is(mean.io structure )

```
-packages
--  User
---   Model
---   Controller
---   Router
--  Address
---   Model
---   Controller
---   Router
--  Orders
---   Model
---   Controller
---   Router
```

Now I want to use address model and order model in user controller. What is the efficient way to work with this file structure and waterline .

Thanks

Comment: A good starting point, albeit not a perfect one, is: https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/blob/master/example/express/express-example.js

You would have to replace the collections initialisation for something like:

`var User = Waterline.Collection.extend(require('./User/Model'));`

Comment: @Dário Thank you for response. I can not understand your answer. can you elaborate more your answer. Plus what is the best way to combine all controllers in app. Because my structure is like 
app <- userRouter <- userController <- userModel <- schema
How can I manage this communication in effecient way. 
Thanks

Comment: 9me, the file I've linked shows how you can initialise your waterline instance with models. From then on you need to put the models returned by the waterline instance (the line: [`app.models = models.collections;`](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/blob/master/example/express/express-example.js#L152)) in some global variable so you can refer to them from your controllers. The structure you're using is good and it can be made to work with waterline.

Comment: @Dário Then how can I get model in controller like in mongoose we can get model using var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  Article = mongoose.model('Article').. Is there any way to get model like this waterline.model('article') Thanks

Comment: 9me, there are several ways of doing that, the simplest being a global variable. So, for example, in the initialisation you would do `global.WL_MODELS = models.collections; `. Then, on your controllers you would use `WL_MODELS`, example: `WL_MODELS.article.findOne({ id: 1 })`. Remember that you should initialise waterline when you start your app and only afterwards you actually use the models. It's a slightly different paradigm than mongoose as waterline has to wire associations between tables/adapters.